# copy_to_user not working data is taken from list_for_each

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to develop driver on basis of this example : http://www.linux-mag.com/id/2739/?r=s

Linux 3.13 x86_64

The copy doesn't happen thou printk has shows info available.

Given the snapshot of read call:

```
/* private data */
struct _mydrv_data{
    struct list_head list; /*link list*/
    char info[10];  /* info */
};

LIST_HEAD( mydrv_list); /*list head*/

int read_proc(struct file *filp, char __user *buf,    
                size_t count, loff_t *offp)
{

off_t thischunk_len = 0;
struct _mydrv_data *p;
int ret = 0;
//traverse the list and copy info into buf

list_for_each_entry(p, &mydrv_list, list){
    ret = copy_to_user(buf, p->info, strlen(p->info));
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "ret:%d read proc %s",ret,p->info);

    thischunk_len += strlen(p->info);
    buf += thischunk_len;
    if (count == 0 )
        return thischunk_len;
    count-= thischunk_len;
    }


return thischunk_len;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `copy_to_user` returns a result, the number of bytes that could not be copied (zero on success). But you're quietly discarding that result.

Comment: copy_to_user returns '0' i.e. all bytes are copied.

Comment: Incidently if i move the printk below copy_to_user, i get output " cat /proc/readme" keeps rotating Node No. 1 thru Node No. 15. But others are not visible though the dmesg logs shows that it has written all upto Node No. 99. Why isn't the loop breaking and why i am not able to see all nodes upto Node No. 99.

Comment: So `copy_to_user` is successful. The number of bytes you're copying is `strlen(p->info)`, which means you're not copying the terminating `'\0'` null character. Try adding this inside the loop: `printk(KERN_DEBUG  "count = %zu\n", count);`. The loop terminates only when `count` is *exactly* zero; I wonder if it's skipping over `0`.

Comment: @Keith, `count` jumps over 0 resetting to 65536 (-1).  1) since the loops has only **100 elements** which are about length e.g. "_Node no. 11_" total size comes around **1100 bytes** only the `list_for_`* api should exit.  2) `count==0` check is only for failsafe i was counting on the for loop to exit

Comment: cat /proc/hello only displays 15 nodes where as we are able to process all 99 nodes. here is the log message 
`[224874.502448] ret 0 offset 0 count 8259 thischunk_len 1166 read proc Node No: 98
[224874.502448]   ret 0 offset 0 count 7081 thischunk_len 1178 read proc Node No: 99
[224874.502451]   
[224874.502542] ret 0 offset 0 count 65536 thischunk_len 0 read proc Node No: 0
[224874.502542] ret 0 offset 0 count 65525 thischunk_len 11 read proc Node No: 1
[224874.502545]   
`

Comment: You might as well use `simple_read_from_buffer()`, which is a more sophisticated version of `copy_to_user()`. It takes care of the offset management all by itself.